# Adding object into an array of a document in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Scenario:
There are two collections, one contains products and the other contains reviews. Both products and reviews collection have a field called "productID". Task is to gather all fields from individual review document and add them to the corresponding product document.

My approach:

1. I am trying to collect all the products and then iterate through each one.
2. This is to individually extract productID and pass it over to find all reviews that match with the productID.
3. All the reviews are then stored in a variable.
   4.Finally, I try to update the current product by pushing the extracted fields from documents that match with productID

Code:

```
var cursor = db.products.find({}, {_id: 0})

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var currDoc = cursor.next();
    var pID = currDoc.productID;

    var revs = db.reviews.find({productID: pID}, {
        _id: 0,
        stars: 1,
        reviewTitle: 1,
        reviewText: 1,
})

db.products.update({ productID: pID }, { $push: { reviews: revs } })
```

Expect:

```
products {
    productID: ##,
    productName: "asdfghjkl",
    productPrice: ##.##,
    reviews:
    [
        {
            stars: 1,
            reviewTitle: "Avoid",
            reviewText: "Not very great"
        }
    ]
}
```

Actual:
**BSONError: cyclic dependency detected**

Answer (score 0):

Convert your PID to string. it will return as an object which needs to be changed as string

```
db.products.find().forEach(function(doc){
    var reviews = db.reviews.find({'productId':str(doc._id)}, {
        _id: 0,
        stars: 1,
        reviewTitle: 1,
        reviewText: "Not very great",
    })
    db.products.update({ "_id": doc._id },{ "$set": { "reviews": reviews } });
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.

I see you are using trying to match up reviews.productID with doc._id however, both the reviews and products collection are linked together with the field "productID". By this I mean, to find docs that are products.productID == reviews.productID.

I executed your code with the modifications stated above however the outputs still remains the same. **BSONError: cyclic dependency detected**